# Are there any synonyms for someone who has opted into something?

Tags: word-choice

Ideally anything more substantive than 'participant'.

I wasn't able to find anything using Google search or Word's synonym tool, and I'm looking for a more personable alternative to using the term 'opt-in' as a noun referring to people.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Writers. Synonyms are general the province of English SE, and I'll recommend that the mods migrate this question there.

Comment: you need to define what opt-in means first, as it just means "agree to something"

Comment: "volunteered"??

Answer (score 3):

What context are you looking to use this in?

In some cases, **adopter** might have a similar connotation, in particular as it's more "active" of a choice.  This comes from the 4th meaing on [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/adopter), "To vote or accept".

In other cases, **member** is a good choice:  a marketing list has *members*.  It doesn't have quite such a strong sense of agreeing to be on it, however.

**Subscriber** has a bit more of a positive sense, although it usually has more connotation of proactive agreement (rather than just checking a box while doing something else).

Answer (score 0):

How about aficionado, or [synonyms](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/aficionado) such as believer, enthusiast... or synonyms of [follower](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/follower), patron, fancier, freak... or how about some synonyms of participant, like member, partner, player...

It all depends on the context, but going a bit wild with a thesaurus can never be wrong! :D

Answer (score 0):

**Participants** is the right word. If they were unwilling, they would be 'unwilling participants'.

A common phrase for this is "people who signed up".

I would agree with Joe, though, context is key here - most words imply a context, so that would fit one word more than another.

- Participants in a study
- Respondents in a poll
- Members of a marketing list [@Joe], or of a group
- Subscribers to a viewpoint
- People who signed up to the idea

Sometimes the name of the thing people have opted into is used - organ donors, churchgoers, gym members, marketing list subscribers.